# OpenCL cannot find GPU in Github action pipeline

Tags: ubuntu, rust, github-actions, opencl

Hello my problem is the following: I am running Rust+openCL stuff on ubuntu-latest.

My integration tests are failing the pipeline. My test runs my OpenCL algo on the default platform provided by the OS. It uses the ocl crate (https://crates.io/crates/ocl). Tests run fine locally on Windows machine with Intel GPU.

```
fn test_successful_resize() {
let context = Context::builder().devices(Device::specifier().first()).build().unwrap();

let device = context.devices()[0];

let queue: Queue = Queue::new(&context, device, None).unwrap();

// some more code 

}
```

---

Pipeline code:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  RUST_BACKTRACE: 1

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Load OpenCL
      run: |
        wget -qO - https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/intel-graphics.key |
          sudo apt-key add -
        sudo add-apt-repository \
          'deb [arch=amd64] https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal main'
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install \
          intel-opencl-icd \
          intel-level-zero-gpu level-zero \
          intel-media-va-driver-non-free libmfx1
        sudo apt-get install \
          libigc-dev \
          intel-igc-cm \
          libigdfcl-dev \
          libigfxcmrt-dev \
          level-zero-dev
        sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build
      run: cargo build --verbose

    - name: Run tests
      run: cargo test --verbose|
```

My pipeline fails at the first test. Logs read as follow

> thread 'images::resize::tests::test_resize_with_empty_image_buffer'
> panicked at
> /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ocl-0.19.6/src/standard/platform.rs:182:55:
> Platform::default():

Actually, the context builder which calls `Platform::default` panics. Here is [the method documentation](https://docs.rs/ocl/latest/ocl/struct.Platform.html#impl-Default-for-Platform). As the doc reads, the platform specified by the OCL_DEFAULT_PLATFORM_IDX env variable is fetched. I don't know to what value I should set this env variable to. Moreover, on my windows machine it's not set. And, finally, I am not sure this would solve my problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might need a GPU runner to run this workload. They're currently in [private beta](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-10-31-run-your-ml-workloads-on-github-actions-with-gpu-runners/).

Comment: @BenjaminW. you are absolutely right. I think if I can't mock the platform, device, and queue the only solution will be a self hosted runner.